# How to check excel cell style using formula?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I had one problem to how to make separate column which is bold among 4. Let me explain in detail I'm using excel win 2010. i have questions with 4 multiple answer i want to make separate column with true answer. true answer is bold. In 4 answers one of is bold so checking all 4 which is bold one copy to true answer column check attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: You cannot make formulas which take into consideration cell formats, except perhaps for number formats. It's either VBA, or using filtering. Would you be okay with a filtering solution?

Comment: First Thanks Jerry,Yes.but also i want to copy true answer on separate colunm

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution by filtering:

1. Apply a filter on the columns containing the answers
2. Select the columns containing the answers and do a replace (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
3. Hit the <kbd>Options >></kbd> button and click on Format for the Find and pick Font > Bold
4. For the replace, do the same thing but pick Fill > Yellow (or any other colour you like). You should get something like this now:

   [image]
5. Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd> button so that all the bold answers are now highlighted.
6. Filter the first column of answers by colour so that you have only the highlighted cells. Assuming that the first answer A is in cell B2, put the formula `=B2` in the last column (i.e. 4 columns before and same row) and fill down the formula.
7. Repeat step 6 for all the other answers making sure you are taking the right column in the formula.
8. Remove the colours from the answer columns.

For A, you should have something like:

[image]

For B...

[image]

etc.

At the end, you should have something like this:

[image]

I have added column G to show the different formulas.